# Web service throws "The value 'null' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'." error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, ado.net, local-storage

I have a system which stores data from an online SQL Server database in local storage. Data records are uploaded and downloaded using a web service. I am using an ADO.Net Entity Data Model in my code.

On some upload requests for one table the routine fails when I try to call it giving an error message "The value 'null' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'." This only happens occasionally and I have not worked out how to repeat the problem. I have logged it 80 times in the last month and in that time the routine has been called successfully 1200 times.

I have five fields in the database record for this table that are defined as uniqueidentifiers. Two of these are 'NOT NULL' and the other three are 'NULL'. Here is the 'CREATE TABLE' query showing the guid fields in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Circuit](
[CircuitID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[BoardID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[RCDID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[CircuitMasterID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[DeviceID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CircuitGuid] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[CircuitID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Circuit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Circuit_RCD] FOREIGN KEY([RCDID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[RCD] ([RCDID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Circuit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Circuit_RCD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Circuit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CircuitGuid_Board] FOREIGN KEY([BoardID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Board] ([BoardID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Circuit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CircuitGuid_Board]
GO
```

The data uploaded for the guid fields in this table looks like this:

```
{"__type":"Circuit:#WaspWA","BoardID":"edb5f774-5e5d-490c-860b-73c3419628cf","CircuitID":"e95bbfa3-2af6-49a5-94dd-c98924ec9a62","CircuitMasterID":null,"DeviceID":"daf12fce-675c-46d9-94c4-ed28c63cdf30","RCDID":null}
```

This record was created on one machine uploaded to the online SQL Server database and then downloaded to another machine.

I have other similar tables in the database which never give any problems. It is just this table which I am getting error messages from. The two fields which are defined as 'NOT NULL' (BoardID and CircuitID) always have data in them and are never null.

Is there something obvious that I have missed here?

Comment: You are trying to store an empty/null value in either `CircuitID` and/or `BoardID`. You are receiving a null value but the database won't allow it. I suggest validating the data before storing it. And log and give an error when that happens so you can fix the source data.

Comment: I can see the data that I am passing up to the server and CircuitID and BoardID are always not null. So I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: I'm halfway there! I can now see that I am trying to write 'null' into the CircuitMasterID and not null. I now just need to work out where my js is turning null into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the value 'null', a string, was being written into my local copy of CircuitMasterID rather than null. So when I tried to write this to SQL it didn't like it. The SQL error message shows null in quotes but I was not sure whether this was because it was a string or because the error message put the value in quotes to delineate it.

The value 'null' had found its way into the CircuitMasterID field because I had written the value null out into some HTML and when this was saved back to the field it became 'null'. I am storing data in local storage and this does not give very good type control. Note to self 'must add better type control'.